# How to center text on button w/ a wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I am using a wrapper to align the text on the button but it is still not working. Any ideas on what do do?

```
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}

.pass-btn{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #03DABB 0%, #03DA9A 100%);
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 187px;
    height: 33px;
    border: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
```

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="pass-btn">get pass</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly

```
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

on the button